# Why is Python's 'all' function so slow?

Tags: python, performance

I have wrote some very simple tests (I know, they are not 'conclusive', but they make me curious). I ran with optimization and all that jazz.

```
from time import time

alist = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 24, 48, 64, 128 ]

def all_even( alist ):
    for val in alist:
        if not (val & 1) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def all_even_bad( alist ):
    result = False
    for val in alist:
        if not (val & 1) == 0:
            result = False
        else:
            result = True
    return result

def main():
    start = time()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        all_even( alist )
    print('All even: {0}'.format(time() - start))

    start = time()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        all_even_bad( alist )
    print('All even bad: {0}'.format(time() - start))


    start = time()
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        all( val & 1 == 0 for val in alist )
    print('All one: {0}'.format(time() - start))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get results around:

```
> All even: 2.86299991608 
> All even bad: 3.71399998665 
> All one: 3.89900016785
```

It appears the built in function doesn't bail out early?

Comment: There is definitely something fishy going on here.  You're only looping over a list of 10 items 10000 times.  Your times should not be on the order of seconds.  Also note that your all_even_bad function is completely wrong ;^) (It really is only checking the last element).

Comment: Sorry about that-- I had a whole bunch of tests but didn't think to post all of the code. I tried to post a small but runnable example. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`all()` definitely does exit early, I think the behavior difference is just the result of the overhead required to create the generator.

Here is some proof that `all()` does exit early:

```
In [8]: alist = [3] + [0] * 2**20    # alist bigger, with an early odd

In [10]: %timeit all_even(alist)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 309 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit all_even_bad(alist)
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit all(val & 1 == 0 for val in alist)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 891 ns per loop
```

Note that even though `all()` is slower than `all_even()` here, it is still significantly faster than the version of the function that doesn't exit early.

Comment: The generator is made every iteration? Why else would each loop be so much higher than all_even? If it was the object creation alone, it should only occur the penalty once, I would assume.

Comment: The generator is made on each iteration.  This is a small but constant overhead compared to looping over the list directly, as you do when you call `all_even()` or `all_even_bad()`.

Comment: A better comparison would be to create your functions inside the loop.  The generator object is created inside the loop, the functions are created outside.  Given that the list is so short, this is a significant difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have no elements that fail the test, therefore there is no way for it to short circuit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote a few more tests (quite a few) but hadn't included all of the script here.

Answer (score 1):

Since all of the numbers in your list are in fact even, it could not logically bail out early? The overhead of your `all()` call might come from the construction of a `generator` object.