# Speed difference in similar code in Python

Tags: python, performance, timeit

I have these 3 functions:

```
def is_compatible(values):
    supported_types = [(str, unicode), (int, long)]
    for allowed_types in supported_types:
        if isinstance(values[0], allowed_types):
            return all(isinstance(item, allowed_types) for item in values)
    return False


def is_compatible2(values):
    supported_types = [(str, unicode), (int, long)]
    for allowed_types in supported_types:
        if all(isinstance(item, allowed_types) for item in values):
            return True
    return False


def is_compatible3(values):
    supported_types = [(str, unicode), (int, long)]
    return any(
            all(isinstance(item, allowed_types) for item in values) for
            allowed_types in supported_types
        )
```

Can someone please explain to me, why when I run them with [1,2,3,4,5] as arg in timetit, results are 2.47, 3.07 and 3.94? So the first one is fastest and last one slowst. I simply cannot see any reason for these speed differences. Thanks.

Comment: Please add description what you really want to achieve with those functions. it is not really clear from those definitions.

Comment: You appear to be returning True if all of your values are either `str` or `unicode`   or  if all of them are `int` or `long`.  If there's a mixture (or anything else) it returns False.  Is this correct?

Comment: Purpose of this functions is to try, if everything in list 'values' is either instance of (str, unicode) or (int, long). So for [1,2,3,4,5] all these functions shoud return true, because they are all instances of (int or long).

Comment: Also note that for performance you should define the supported types outside of the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Python's 'all' function so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583869/why-is-pythons-all-function-so-slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer appears to be here: [Why is Python's 'all' function so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583869/why-is-pythons-all-function-so-slow)

Setting up the iterator in `all` takes time.

In your first function you only do this once.  In your second function you occasionally do this twice.  So first beats second.

Your second beats third for the same reason again.  There's more overhead to set up.  A call to `any` wrapped around the `for allowed_types in ...` is more overhead than simply `for allowed_types in ...`.