# Fastest way to check if a string can be created with a list of characters in python

Tags: python

I need to check if a string can be created with a list of characters and return True or False.

I am using different solutions with list.count or collections.Counter.

I am also using this solution which I dont need to read through the list of characters:

```
def check(message, characters):
    try:
        [list(characters).remove(m) for m in message]
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Is there a fastest way? for a very very very big list of characters. Counter and list count seems slower. Dont know if there is a fast pythonic way to do this.

Example:

```
message = "hello"
characters = "hheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfd"

check(message, characters) # this should return True or False
# characters can be a veeeeery long string
```

**Duplicates matter** so for example characters = "hheloo" would not work for message = "hello"

Comment: can you post an example? I would do it with `set`s if duplicates do not matter.

Comment: Duplicates matters, thats why I cant use set

Comment: Yep sorry, that would Not work for message hello

Comment: There might be some things to short-circuit some cases. For example checking the `len(set(characters))` that has to be at least equal or bigger than the  `len(set(message))`. Or that the `set(characters) - set(message)` is not an empty set.. These do not guarantee success but the can spot failure early.

Comment: *“characters can be a veeeeery long string”* – Even more reason to not store it as a string. Ideally, it should be a constant counter, but if you have to have it as a string, at least keep it *sorted*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Just build two counters and use the [`subtract()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract) method to check if there're any negative counts:

```
>>> c1 = Counter(characters)
>>> c2 = Counter(message)
>>> c1.subtract(c2)
>>> all(v >= 0 for v in c1.values())
False
```

This should work in linear time.

Comment: I doubt that creating a `Counter` is done in linear time though, since it iterates the `iterable` and sorts its contents into buckets (which have a lookup time themselves as well). But may depend on the actual implementation.

Comment: `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so set item is `O(1)` on average. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @jbndlr `Counter` uses a dictionary under the covers: Creation and insertion is done in constant time (average case), and you only need to iterate the input string once. So you get linear time.

Comment: Thanks I was using Counter in another possible solution but didnt know about the subtract method

Answer (score 1):

This is not feasible in linear time, as the length of both strings matter and they need to be iterated for each character. Without having checked its actual implementation, I assume `remove()` is logarithmic.

```
def check(msg, chars):
    c = list(chars)  # Creates a copy
    try:
        for m in msg:
            c.remove(m)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check('hello', 'ehlo'))
    print(check('hello', 'ehlol'))
    print(check('hello', 'ehloijin2oinscubnosinal'))
```

Comment: How is that generally different from what OP is already doing?

Comment: It does not create a new list using a comprehension. Futhermore, OP is creating a new list instance in each iteration of the comprehension. OP's code is not even working ;)

Comment: Well, that’s the problem with OP’s attempt to solve this, but it’s still the exact same approach.

Comment: Quote from OP's question: _"I am using different solutions with list.count or collections.Counter"_

Comment: `list.remove` is linear, so this solution is quadratic in time.

Comment: Yes, its my bad, I wrote my solution too fast and I am creating a list in every iteration but at the end is the same solution as yours. I am looking for a totally different approach without try/except and removing from other list/string

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution compared to eugene's solution and jbndlr's solution.

```
def test1(input_word, alphabet):
    alp_set = set(list(alphabet))
    in_set = set(list(input_word))
    return in_set.issubset(alp_set)

def test2(input_word, alphabet):
    c1 = collections.Counter(alphabet)
    c2 = collections.Counter(input_word)
    c1.subtract(c2)
    return all(v >= 0 for v in c1.values())

def check(msg, chars):
    c = list(chars)  # Creates a copy
    try:
        for m in msg:
            c.remove(m)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

input_word = "hello"
alphabet = "hheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfd"


start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    test1(input_word,alphabet)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    test2(input_word,alphabet)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
   for i in range(10000):
       check(input_word,alphabet)
   print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

>> --- 0.03100299835205078 seconds ---
>> --- 0.24402451515197754 seconds ---
>> --- 0.022002220153808594 seconds ---
```

⇒ jbndlr's solution is the fastest - for this test case.

Another testcase:

```
input_word = "hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello"
alphabet =
```

"hheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfdhheellooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfd"

```
>> --- 0.21964788436889648 seconds ---
>> --- 0.518169641494751 seconds ---
>> --- 1.3148927688598633 seconds ---
```

⇒ test1 is fastest

Comment: Is set solution taking care about repetitions?

Comment: Could you possibly explain a bit more what test1 is doing step by step?

Comment: `test1` will not care about the count of characters in each string, so it’s not a solution to OP’s problem.

Comment: @poke True, thanks. I will think about a fix for that.

Comment: I can't think of a way to fix that using build in comparisons, therefore I delete this solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a faster way of doing this, apparently due to the cost of creating the all() generator ([Why is Python's 'all' function so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583869/why-is-pythons-all-function-so-slow)) perhaps a for loop is faster, Expanding on @eugene y's answer:

```
from collections import Counter
import time

message = "hello"
characters = "hheeooasdadsfgfdgfdhgfdlkgkfd"

def check1(message,characters):
    c1 = Counter(characters)
    c2 = Counter(message)
    c1.subtract(c2)
    return all(v > -1 for v in c1.values())

def check2(message,characters):
    c1 = Counter(characters)
    c2 = Counter(message)
    c1.subtract(c2)
    for v in c1.values():
        if v < 0:
            return False
    return True

st = time.time()
for i in range(350000):
    check1(message,characters)
end = time.time()
print ("all(): "+str(end-st))

st = time.time()
for i in range(350000):
    check2(message,characters)
end = time.time()
print ("for loop: "+str(end-st))
```

results:

```
all(): 5.201688051223755
for loop: 4.864434719085693
```